# How to create a basic "name that word" quiz.

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a basic quiz which asks me to name a predetermined list of words in order from first to last.

I created a function that asks for a word, then accepts my input. If my word is the same as the word being asked for, then the function should print "Good job!" and move onto the next word. If my word isn't the correct word it should print "Nope! Try again: " and let me type in another word.

The function asks me for a word but when I type in the correct word, it keeps printing "Nope! Try again: " and asking me for another word, as if I typed in the wrong word. This loop seems to be endless, no matter what I type.

1. In my code what am I doing wrong?
2. This code feels really messy to me, and I know there must be a way for me to write it cleaner/using fewer lines. Any suggestions for how I can do that?

Code:

```
def answers
  words = [
    "Hello",
    "My",
    "Name",
    "Is",
    "Josh",
    "And",
    "I",
    "Am",
    "A",
    "Total",
    "Idiot"
  ]

    print "1: "
      answer0 = gets.to_s
        while answer0 != words[0]
          print "Nope. Try again: "
          answer0 = gets.to_s
        end
        puts "Good job!"

    print "2: "
      answer1 = gets.to_s
        while answer1 != words[1]
          print "Nope. Try again: "
          answer1 = gets.to_s
        end
        puts "Good job!"

    print "3: "
      answer2 = gets.to_s
        while answer2 != words[2]
          print "Nope. Try again: "
          answer1 = gets.to_s
        end
        puts "Good job!"
end

puts "Try to name all the WORDS, in order. Go!"

answers
```

Comment: Please add a descriptive title that describes your problem

Comment: Gotcha. Changing the title now Andrew L. Thank you

Comment: Suggestion for cleaner code: don't mess with indentation like that. :)

Comment: I'd strong suggest reading "[ask]" and the linked pages, especially http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. Please don't beg, it doesn't help. We're here to help. You're here to get help. Write an accurate, detailed question that is to the point. We don't care about your experience, only that you put in the effort to research your question, and to work hard to solve it. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" discusses this.

Comment: Copy that -- thanks Sergio and Tin Man. Working every day on doing the research, appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` returns a string with the trailing newline. Get rid of the newline

```
answer0 = gets.chomp
```

ProTip: when you get stuck in a similar situation (two seemingly same pieces of data don't match or something), start debug-printing all the things. In your case, I'd start with something like this:

```
answer0 = gets.to_s
puts "comparing #{answer0.inspect} to #{words[0].inspect}"

while answer0 != words[0]
```

Then you can analyze the debug output visually and see for yourself if the strings are equal or not. The `.inspect` part is important.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sergio. I hadn't yet heard of the .inspect method -- am reading about it now and it's super helpful. I'll look to start debug-printing things piece by piece to see where I'm going wrong. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's most powerful learning and debugging utility is the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) tool `irb`. There you can experiment with different approaches and try code one line at a time.

The first thing to observe is `gets` pulls strings that usually have a newline character at the end. You type in "hello" and you get `"hello\n"`. The usual method for mitigating this is `gets.chomp`. For some reason you're using `gets.to_s` which is a very strange thing to do.

Another thing is that `gets` can return `nil` which means there's no more input. You never test for this, in fact the `.to_s` call prevents that, so you might end up stuck in a loop if someone terminates their input before you're ready. On many systems ^D (CTRL+D) will do this.

One of the things you'll want to do when programming is look for blocks of similar code and replace them with functions or wrap them in loops so that the duplication is eliminated or minimized. You can see those "print" blocks are largely the same, generally differing by a single digit. What if you could iterate through a series of digits?

This is actually pretty easy because of the [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method. Combine that with a `case` statement to make your three possible outcomes clear, wrap it in a loop that asks for input and this code shrinks dramatically:

```
words.each_with_index do |word, i|
  print "What's word #%d?" % (i + 1)

  loop do
    guess = gets

    case guess && guess.chomp.downcase
    when nil
      puts "\nWell, okay then."

      exit(0)
    when word
      puts "Good job!"
      break
    else
      print "Nope, try again: "
    end
  end
end
```

The three outcomes are: correct guess, end of input, and incorrect guess. All of these should be handled correctly now.

The principle you violated here is the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) by having a fixed number of `print` blocks. A proper implementation makes no assumptions about how many words there are, and as you add or remove elements from the array it adapts accordingly.

Comment: tadman -- this is so awesome. Thanks a ton. In all my reading, somehow I still hadn't heard of the .each_with_index method. Can I ask -- what do those vertical lines in |word, i| do? Are they different from () and [ ]?

Comment: Cool -- reading about the Zero, One or Infinity rule too. Makes perfect sense. Slowly learning that the better way to go is to create a function (like you did above) that can adjust itself no matter how many elements are put into it. The same rules should apply regardless of the number.

Comment: @JoshWeisman: "what do those vertical lines in |word, i| do" - they denote block parameters. Yes, they are different from those other ones. Read about blocks.